# I am playing around with Spring, Maven and Eclipse, force Maven2 to copy dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-2

I am playing around in Eclipse trying to get Maven to load dependency to my Springs project.. I am new to maven so this is giving me a hard time.  I am trying to force Maven2 to copy dependencies into target/lib in eclipse but dont know the right way to do it.

I am getting the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e.  pom.xml /TestSpringMaven    line 54 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSpringMaven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestSpringMaven Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>TestSpringMaven</finalName>

        <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>install</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why are you specifically trying to get Maven to copy the libraries? You don't need to if you just want them to get deployed or use them on the compilation classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse automatically includes the maven dependencies in build path. Make sure you `right click your project --> Maven --> Enable Dependency Management`
The jar files are automatically copied to `WEB-INF\lib\` of your war. 
If you follow maven defaults, life will be much easier.